# Penrose diagram of de Sitter spacetime: Constant time curve on $r>R$ domain

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, de-sitter-spacetime

I have to draw penrose diagram of $dS_4$, with its constant time and space curves.

Static patch of $dS_4$: $$ds^2=-(1-(r/R)^2)dt^2+1/(1-(r/R)^2)dr^2+r^2d\Omega_2^2$$

And conformally transformed into Penrose coordinates: $$ds^2=(R^2/\cos^2(\eta))(-d\eta^2+d\chi^2+\sin^2(\chi)d\Omega_2^2)$$

with parameter domain $\eta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and $\chi\in[0,\pi]$

(I used equal parametrization with David Tong's Lecture note.)

Here, comparing Omega terms between two coords, I derived the relation between $\eta$ and $\chi$ for constant $r=\alpha\times R$

Constant $r$ curve : $\alpha=\sin(\chi)/\cos(\eta)$

This works well (via python):

[image: constant r curves]

Also, assuming $r<R$, using $R(4,1)$ embedding, I derived the curve of constant $t$ (Here, following global coord. notations are used)
Global coordinates : $$ds^2=-d\tau^2+R^2\cosh^2(\tau/R)d\Omega_3^2$$

Derivation: $$X^{4}=\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\cosh(t/R)=R\cos(\tau/R)\cos(\chi)=R\cos(\chi)/\cos(\eta)$$
Constant $t$ curve($r<R$) : $$\cos^2(\eta)\cosh^2(\beta)=1+\sin^2(\chi)\sinh^2(\beta)$$ where $\beta=t/R$

However, this equation cannot describe $r>R$ region, since parametrization of embedding does not covers global region.. or imaginary time.

Therefore, I am trying to derive relation between $\eta$ and $\chi$ for constant time, on $r>R$ condition.

I seriously need help.